# A: You haven't heard it? B: No, I heard it (nodding a yes)

Tags: american-english, questions, speech, pragmatics

- A: You haven't heard it? B: **No**, I heard it (nodding a yes)

I'd always expect as a positive response to a negative question ***Yes***, I heard it / did.

Why so?

[Link to video](https://youtu.be/2OjTa8ok3lA?t=1352) 22:32

Comment: This is a perfectly normal response.  The first speaker has made an assertion, and the second speaker is responding that the assertion is untrue.

Comment: Like the OP, I would expect the reply 'Yes, I have.'

Comment: @Kate That would be a different response. The negative response is directly commenting on the veracity of A’s statement, correcting a misconception. The positive response is just answering the question. It would also be quite natural to double the negation in the negative response: “No no, I heard it”.

Comment: @HotLicks If it **was** an assertion, then No might be reasonable. As it's expressed in the question here, it's a question "You haven't heard it?" to which Yes is reasonable if the answerer has heard it. It seems likely in the interview that the sentence was intended and interpreted as an assertion.

Comment: What's strange is that *No, I haven't heard it* is *also* a natural response. But the *no* is being used contextually. The first *no* is a rejection of the claim while the second *no* is an affirmation of the claim.

Comment: I'd say both versions are acceptable if clarification is given immediately afterwards.  In spoken English, clarification can be intoned, whereas in written English, clarification should be explicit.

Comment: @Andrew I wouldn’t have thought this was a BrE/AmE difference, but given that the two Brits who’ve commented both find the ‘no’ here unexpected, while the two Americans who’ve commented both say it’s perfectly normal, perhaps it is. I have to side with the Americans here: I find it completely natural and perfectly unremarkable. It seems to me that the ‘no’ here is answering an implied question, whereas ‘yes’ would be answering the stated question; e.g., “What’s the matter? Didn’t you hear me?” – “No [i.e., that’s not what’s wrong], I heard you, it’s just that…”.

Comment: → In this case, Sway is asking “You haven’t heard his rap?” in response to Eminem’s statement that he’s going to wait a bit to see what comes out of some situation (concerning this rap) before taking action. Eminem then replies ‘no’ to the implied question whether his decision to wait is because he hasn’t heard the rap yet, adding that he has in fact heard it. He doesn’t follow up with a different reason for waiting, but it’s implied that there is one. (@Andrew)

Comment: If the response was meant to be not merely informative but clearly contradictory, that might be so; otherwise, why would you expect a negative - or positive - response to any query?

Answer (score -2):

Actually, in English, you always say YES if your answer
is POSITIVE, and say NO if your answer is NEGATIVE
 regardless of how the question is phrased.

Example:
(1) Have you finished your lunch?
     Yes, I have; or No, I haven't.
(2) Have you not finished your homework?
     Yes, I have; or No, I haven't.

It may not be true in some languages such as Chinese.

Comment: Hi Victor, welcome to EL&U. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's not enough to just say "you always do X" - what's your evidence for this rule? You can [edit] your post to add a reference; for further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: This is not true. It’s true of the basic functions of yes and no (which work the same way in Chinese, incidentally; you’re thinking of Japanese), but there are many exceptions. You can use a negative with a positive answer as in the question here, and you can also use an affirmative with a negative answer if you’re being sarcastic (“I’m the greatest poet ever, aren’t I?” — “Yeah, I don’t think so.”).